# Does Livewire replaces Vue.js/React.js in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I need to have functionalities provided by Vue.js/React.js in Laravel.
Does Livewire replaces the above(Vue.js/React.js)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no its not exactly.

- in **old-fashion** front end developing, backend sends Html codes to the client browser to render.  it could be more feature rich using css and js and other assets.
- some times its getting messy to mix server-side script with html, so **tempting languages** has been appeared. ex : **blade**
  templating engine translate blade into php which produce Html

but it was 2 problems:

1. when a user navigate to another page. he had to load a lots of redundant data like site's header, footer, ...
2. from developer view, front-end developer had to develop some server-side coding, and they got coupled (server-side code with client-side code)

so a new method emerges:

- **Single Page Applications framework** (like React and Vue), they were js codes which could get **just new additional data** for each page.

The web application with all html css ... remains and just another pages content get downloaded with the **JS** and replaced with content.

and it decoupled **front-end** code from back-end too.

but it could be a little harder to implement method for some developers which **has not separated backend and frontend developer**.

if a developer wanted to use this benefits (loading data simply with ajax)

it gets a little complicate for him and he had to learn ho to develop front-end component ....

### LiveWire

Livewire is a new Technology that laravel offers that is easier for a backend developer to develop a front end with SPA Frameworks.

- its simple as blade.
- can be efficient data transferring with ajax calls
- as long as it use module based component it can be reusable like react component

but:

- its not going to decouple front-end with backend codes
- it dosent provide all the features of SPA Framework like : routing,client MVC, ...

> I name it of it just Blade instead of JSX